# Adding Rollover Text to a Sprite using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I'm creating a site where the homepage has rollover sprites with text that appears  underneath the images on rollover. The image sprite already has an active state on rollover. I want to add an additional state: live text that appears underneath the image. I've found many solutions that can create text that appears when you roll over a plain image. However, I am unable to make it work with a sprite, mainly because the sprite's image has to live in the css and many of the examples that I've seen use it in the HTML. If someone could let me know if this is even possible using CSS or if I should try it with Javascript, it would be much appreciated!

Here is the **HTML** for the rollover sprite:

```
<div id="image_1">
    <a href="project_1.html"></a>
    <div class="roll_title">
         <h4>Title</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.roll_title {
    margin: 170px 0 0 0;
    text-align:center;
}

#image_1 {
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-image:url(../i/patria_roll.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:left;
    margin: 50px 0 0 30px;
}

#image_1:hover {
    background-position-y: -150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an absolute position `.roll_title` with `display: hidden;` inside `#image_1` and change its display property to `display: block;` when `#image_1` is hovered.
Here's a live example:

http://jsbin.com/doyer/1/

Comment: It works for me. When you hover over the red box it becomes black and title text appears. Red and black backgrounds are parts of a background sprite. Isn't that what you trying to do?